# Какое ударение в слове бурекас?

Tags: ударение

Нигде не пишут на какой слог ставить ударение в слове [бурекас](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81). Слово, как я вижу, имеет корни в турецком и греческом языках, а также в иврите. В google translate на греческом языке воспроизведение вроде ударение ставит на бурекАс.

Comment: В греческом ударение на Е: ед.ч. μπουρέκι (бурéки), мн.ч. μπουρέκια (бурéкия). https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/μπουρέκι

Answer (score 1):

Это слово попало в русский из идиш и произносится с ударением на Е: *буре́кас.*

А вот бурек, который в Википедии перечислен через запятую, имеет ударение на У. Так произносят в странах бывшей Югославии, где эти пирожки являются популярным фаст-фудом.

Answer (score 0):

A cursory glance over Youtube videos (recorded mostly by Russian-speaking Israelis) shows that the vast majority of them put the stress on the second syllable: *буре́кас*

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ydnb-9gThw
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMsbYhNIKqE
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEZ8FI6BK0k

Comment: [Wiktionary has](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%A1) the stress on the 2nd syllable for Hebrew בּוּרֶקָס (burékas), that can be the reason why Israelis have it on the 2nd syllable even while talking Russian. In Serbo-Croatian and Slovene the stress is on U: [bùrek](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burek#Noun_5). Anyhow, the stress on E closely follows the original Turkish stress, which is good in every respect.